# Keep form value after clicking the browser's back button

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cross-browser

Is there any way to keep data on text input after successfully submitted the form and retain the value after clicking the back button?

i am using cakephp 1.3.xx

TIA :D

Comment: thanks... this really gives me a whole day pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use localStorage at the client side?

Comment: i used javascript on all forms and elements... on first load the forms are hidden until the users some elements to show the form and then after successfully submitted the form and when the user hit the back button all data has been cleared out

Comment: Please research localStorage. It's not just javascript

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a browser configuration, however, if you simply do not redirect after the form is submitted, you can stay with the form data again by setting the variable `$data`:

```
$this->set('data', $this->data);
```

Comment: this happens on registration.. if the user provides all the needed information he will be redirected to payment method.. the problem is.. if the user hit the back button all the data or value in form has been cleared.. BTW thanks for your response